# .US domain seo google problem

Tags: google, seo

I recently brought **keyword.us** where keyword has:

- 180 millions searches per month (Worldwide)
- 40 millions searches per month (America)

Now how bad is my move? keyword.com is already registered.

Will I get a penalty for that? Will I be invisible on google.co.uk, google.com, google.fr?

Comment: Giant Google logos are useless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be conflating the effects of [geotargeting](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=62399) with an explicit drop in rank.

It's not really that your .us domain will be directly blocked or pushed down in results on google.fr(and .co.uk, etc.), but that ccTLD sites are given a small boost at their associated google.tld. This is because it's reasonable to assume that French users on google.fr are probably more interested in French results. So yes, your .us domain might–*might*–show up a little lower at google.fr, but it's not because you were penalized; it's because the French results are more *relevant* to the users of that particular Google version. Assuming you got the .com, if a document there were equally ranked with some other .fr document, the .fr would still probably come out above.

Comment: thank you ... i was thinking on buying all domains fr es co.uk ... and so on, and rank on all of them, because those days you can buy a good domain name

Answer (score 0):

Google does not exclude or penalize<sup>[citation needed]</sup> search results from foreign ccTLDs.

Comment: are you shure about that?? my seo expert told me that if i wanned to rank on google.us then get an .us , if i want to rank on .com then buy a .com ....

Comment: There is no `google.us`.

Comment: Many TLDs are bought for vanity value (especially `.tv` or `.me`).

Comment: @Row Minds you really need to stop listening to whomever is giving you that SEO advice.

Comment: There is a boost for country specific domains and content on country specific google sites though.  This can clearly be seen by comparing results for the same search on each.